# Mapped explicitly for geo_point using scala

Tags: scala, indexing, elasticsearch, kibana

Ok, i am trying to generate geo-points in my index in Kibana for use the map.

This is my code:

```
 import org.apache.spark.{SparkContext, SparkConf}
  import org.elasticsearch.spark._

 object KibanaIndice {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {


val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("PruebaKibana")
conf.set("es.index.auto.create", "true").set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "false")

val sc = new SparkContext(conf)


val mapa  = Seq(

  Map("year" -> "2014-01-11","total" -> 123,"aprobadas"->12,"days"->33,"formalizadas"->8, "loca"-> "41.722, -34.456"),
  Map("year" -> "2014-02-11","total" -> 223,"aprobadas"->43,"days"->28,"formalizadas"->22,"loca"-> "42.722, -34.456"),
  Map("year" -> "2014-03-11","total" -> 154,"aprobadas"->112,"days"->10,"formalizadas"->26, "loca"-> "43.722, -34.456"),
  Map("year" -> "2014-04-11","total" -> 333,"aprobadas"->221,"days"->33,"formalizadas"->100, "loca"-> "44.722, -34.456"),
  Map("year" -> "2014-05-11","total" -> 445,"aprobadas"->411,"days"->12,"formalizadas"->343, "loca"-> "45.722, -34.456"),
  Map("year" -> "2014-06-11","total" -> 64,"aprobadas"->55,"days"->28,"formalizadas"->36, "loca"-> "46.722, -34.456"),
  Map("year" -> "2014-07-11","total" -> 34,"aprobadas"->22,"days"->28,"formalizadas"->16, "loca"-> "47.722, -34.456"),
  Map("year" -> "2014-08-11","total" -> 2344,"aprobadas"->2134,"days"->23,"formalizadas"->1322, "loca"-> "48.722, -34.456"),
  Map("year" -> "2014-09-11","total" -> 433,"aprobadas"->344,"days"->21,"formalizadas"->256, "loca"-> "49.722, -34.456"),
  Map("year" -> "2014-10-11","total" -> 312,"aprobadas"->190,"days"->22,"formalizadas"->26, "loca"-> "50.722, -34.456"),
  Map("year" -> "2014-11-11","total" -> 1100,"aprobadas"->900,"days"->21,"formalizadas"->444, "loca"-> "51.722, -34.456"),
  Map("year" -> "2014-12-11","total" -> 234,"aprobadas"->201,"days"->21,"formalizadas"->144, "loca"-> "52.722, -34.456"),
  Map("year" -> "2015-01-11","total" -> 200,"aprobadas"->140,"days"->33,"formalizadas"->21, "loca"-> "53.722, -34.456"),
  Map("year" -> "2015-02-11","total" -> 234,"aprobadas"->94,"days"->28,"formalizadas"->62, "loca"-> "54.722, -34.456"),
  Map("year" -> "2015-03-11","total" -> 100,"aprobadas"->91,"days"->10,"formalizadas"->76, "loca"-> "55.722, -34.456"),
  Map("year" -> "2015-04-11","total" -> 180,"aprobadas"->78,"days"->33,"formalizadas"->60, "loca"-> "56.722, -34.456"),
  Map("year" -> "2015-05-11","total" -> 220,"aprobadas"->50,"days"->12,"formalizadas"->43, "loca"-> "57.722, -34.456"),
  Map("year" -> "2015-06-11","total" -> 311,"aprobadas"->55,"days"->28,"formalizadas"->6, "loca"-> "58.722, -34.456"),
  Map("year" -> "2015-07-11","total" -> 145,"aprobadas"->65,"days"->28,"formalizadas"->36, "loca"-> "59.722, -34.456"),
  Map("year" -> "2015-08-11","total" -> 345,"aprobadas"->58,"days"->23,"formalizadas"->22, "loca"-> "60.722, -34.456"),
  Map("year" -> "2015-09-11","total" -> 233,"aprobadas"->70,"days"->21,"formalizadas"->56, "loca"-> "61.722, -34.456"),
  Map("year" -> "2015-10-11","total" -> 312,"aprobadas"->190,"days"->22,"formalizadas"->56, "loca"->"62.722, -34.456"),
  Map("year" -> "2015-11-11","total" -> 190,"aprobadas"->90,"days"->21,"formalizadas"->44, "loca"->"63.722, -34.456"),
  Map("year" -> "2015-12-11","total" -> 194,"aprobadas"->100,"days"->19,"formalizadas"->41, "loca"->"64.722, -34.456")
)


sc.makeRDD(mapa).saveToEs("geolol/geo_point")

}
```

}

In loca i try to pass an string with coordenates as documentation say, i asume that i must create the index telling that loca type is geo-point, but i dont know how to do.

Thanks for all.

Answer (score 1):

If your index is not built yet, you have to create it by yourself in elasticsearch and map `"loca"` as a geo type. This is example taken from documentation:

```
PUT /attractions
{
  "mappings": {
    "restaurant": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "location": {
          "type": "geo_point"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

By default, it's going to understand your numbers as integers and index it as an array of them.

Comment: With the scala program i create a new index but i think that is not a problem because when you execute the program the write in the index without delete the data that had stored. I try the solution that you suggest but the string loca"-> "57.722, -34.456" is evaluated as a string not as a geo-point.

Comment: Can you rewrite it as an array? Something like: `"loca" -> Array(59.722, -34.456)`?

Comment: I try to write as an array (23.3443, -22323.233) but it dosent works. Really is difficult to find documentation about map with kibana.

Comment: Buddy can you check the git page of es-hadoop. I guess there was some defect raised by someone regarding geo points which got fixed in recent builds. That might help you.